# Exercise in Calculus of Variation: Upper bound for energy functional

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, calculus-of-variations

> Consider the following functional:
>
> $\;E(u)=\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{2}{\vert u' \vert}^2+W(u)\;dx\;$
>   where $\;u \in C^4(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^2)\;,\;W \in C^3(\mathbb
>  R^2;\mathbb R)\;$
>
> - Denote $\;S:=\{$the set in which the energy functional is minimized$\}\;$ and assume the difference of elements of $\;S\;$
>     belongs to $\;W^{1,2}(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^2)\;$
> - Let $\;u \in S\;$ and $\;F \subset S\;$, the the distance from $\;u\;$ to $\;F\;$ in the $\;W^{1,2}-$norm is: $\;d(u,F)=inf\{{\vert
>    \vert u-v \vert \vert}_{W^{1,2}}: v\in F\}\;$
> - Call $\;\mathcal Z\;$ the set of all minimizers of $\;E\;$ over $\;S\;$ and $\;C(z)=\{z(\cdot-m):m\in \mathbb R\;,\;z\in \mathcal
>    Z\}\;$
> - $\;e_1=\min\{E(u):u\in S\}\;$
>
> If there are strictly positive numbers $\;a,b,c\;$ such that:
>
> - $\;\forall a\gt 0\;\Rightarrow \inf\{E(u):u\in S\;,\;d(u,\mathcal Z)\ge a\}\gt e_1\;$
> - if $\;d(u,\mathcal Z \setminus C(z))\gt 0\;$ and $\;d(u,C(z)) \lt b \Rightarrow E(u)-e_1\ge c{d(u,C(z))}^2\;$
>
> Prove that $\;\forall a\in(0,d(z,\mathcal Z \setminus C(z))\;$ there
>   exists $\;\beta \gt 0\;$ such that:
>
> $\;d(u,\mathcal Z \setminus C(z)) \ge a \Rightarrow E(u)-e_1 \ge \beta
>  \min\{1,{d(u,C(z))}^2\}\;$

Our professor said that this kind of exercise is quite easy since it follows immediately from the two last inequalities. However I'm having a really hard time solving this.

**My Attempt:**

$\;E(u)-e_1 \ge \beta \min\{1,{d(u,C(z))}^2\}\;$ implies that I should have had $\;E(u)-e_1 \ge \beta\;$ and $\;E(u)-e_1 \ge \beta {d(u,C(z))}^2\;$. The second inequality is given from the data. Now for the first one, I believe since $\;\inf\{E(u):u\in S\;,\;d(u,\mathcal Z)\ge a\}\gt e_1\;$ it follows $\;E(u) \ge e_1+\beta\;$ for some $\;\beta \gt 0\;$

Moreover in order for all the above inequalities to hold, it should $\;d(u,\mathcal Z\setminus C(z))\ge a\;$ since $\;\mathcal Z\setminus C(z) \subset \mathcal Z \Rightarrow d(u,\mathcal Z\setminus C(z)) \ge d(u,\mathcal Z) \ge a\;$

Still, I'm a bit unsure if the above thoughts are valid. I would appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance